# менять фон сайта при смене слайда

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="main_body">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div id="first_item" class="item active">
                    <div class="first-slide col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-5 complect">
                            <p class="stroy">КОМПЛЕКТАЦИЯ<br>СТРОИТЕЛЬНЫХ<br>ОБЪЕКТОВ</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 second_block">
                            <p class="sec_block">Замкнутое множество традиционно привлекает ряд<br>
                                Тейлора. До недавнего времени считалось, что график<br>
                                функции многих переменных транслирует параллельный<br>
                                бином Ньютона, откуда следует доказываемое равенство.
                            </p>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger index_button">Узнать больше</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn  btn-defaul_index">Все услуги</button>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="second_item" class="item">
                    <div class="first-slide col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-5 complect">
                            <p class="stroy">КОМПЛЕКТАЦИЯ<br>СТРОИТЕЛЬНЫХ<br>ОБЪЕКТОВ</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 second_block">
                            <p class="sec_block">Замкнутое множество традиционно привлекает ряд<br>
                                Тейлора. До недавнего времени считалось, что график<br>
                                функции многих переменных транслирует параллельный<br>
                                бином Ньютона, откуда следует доказываемое равенство.
                            </p>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger index_button">Узнать больше</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn  btn-defaul_index">Все услуги</button>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="third_item" class="item">
                    <div class="first-slide col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-5 complect">
                            <p class="stroy">КОМПЛЕКТАЦИЯ<br>СТРОИТЕЛЬНЫХ<br>ОБЪЕКТОВ</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 second_block">
                            <p class="sec_block">Замкнутое множество традиционно привлекает ряд<br>
                                Тейлора. До недавнего времени считалось, что график<br>
                                функции многих переменных транслирует параллельный<br>
                                бином Ньютона, откуда следует доказываемое равенство.
                            </p>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger index_button">Узнать больше</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn  btn-defaul_index">Все услуги</button>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
         </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</div> это код самого слайдера и основного блока main_body у которого нужно менять фон... я слаб в jquery и пока получилось вот это 
 if($("#first_item").hasClass("active")){}
         $(".main_body").css({'background-image': 'url(../images/mainbackground.jpg)'});
     }

 if($("#second_item").hasClass("active"))
         $(".main_body").css({'background-image': 'url(../images/mainbackground-double.jpg)'});

  if($("#third_item").hasClass("active"))
          $(".main_body").css({'background-image': 'url(../images/mainbackground_third.jpg)'});
```

но это не работает, буду рад любой помощи

Comment: какой слайдер используете?

Comment: bootstrap, у него меняется класс active но у меня не получается менять фон почему т

Comment: надо менять фон у main_body при смене слайда...я слайдам дал разные id (#second_item, #third_item, #first_item)

Comment: вам надо отслеживать событие смены слайда

Comment: я пробовал как показал выше, но не получается...отслеживаю смену класса active

Comment: я не вижу, что бы писали о событии отслеживания. вы просто проверяете класс. но ваша проверка сработает при загрузке страницы, но когда вы смените слайд - ваш код не сработает, то есть он не проверит что класс active перешел на другой слайд. поэтому я и говорю, что вам надо отслеживать событие смены слайда

Comment: можете подсказать как? я не понимаю...я новичок в jquery

Comment: `$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () { ***тут ваш код проверки*** })`

Comment: ну и вместо `#myCarousel` вы должны подставить id своего слайдера

Comment: у меня id такой же

Comment: $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () { 
     if($("#first_item").hasClass("active")){}
         $(".main_body").css({'background-image': 'url(../images/mainbackground.jpg)'});
     }

 if($("#second_item").hasClass("active"))
         $(".main_body").css({'background-image': 'url(../images/mainbackground-double.jpg)'});

  if($("#third_item").hasClass("active"))
          $(".main_body").css({'background-image': 'url(../images/mainbackground_third.jpg)'});  
 })   попробовал вот так но не получается, может что то не так вставил?

Comment: а если вместо вашего кода просто написать `alert(1)` - он покажется?

Comment: да,показывает, значит, что то не так с моим кодом?

Comment: вы можете дать ссылку? или вы на локалке делаете?

Comment: на локале делаю...можете дать почту я скину?

Comment: спасибо, все получилось!

Comment: что было не так?

Comment: это я тупонул, пути неправильно указал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно поместить свой код сюда

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () { ***тут ваш код проверки*** })
```